# Replace specific character of element from pandas series

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

I have got this pandas series for ex;

```
data = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C', 'AabX', 'BacX','', np.nan, 'CABA', 'dog', 'cat'])
```

now, I want to replace every 'X' of the element and 'dog' with PP.

so my final outcome will be:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'AabPP', 'BacPP','', np.nan, 'CABA', 'PP', 'cat']
```

I did this:

```
data.str.replace('X','PP')
```

I got this:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'AabPP', 'BacPP','', np.nan, 'CABA', 'dog', 'cat']
```

But can I do a replacement for 'dog' at the same time? Or do i need to do same process again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need replace for substring `X` and for `dog` with no substrings use `|` for regex `or` and add `^` for start of string and `$` for end of string:

```
df = data.str.replace('X|^dog$','PP', regex=True)
#alternative 
df = data.replace('X|^dog$','PP', regex=True)
```

If need replace by substrings `X` or `dog` use:

```
df = data.str.replace('X|dog','PP', regex=True)
#alternative 
df = data.replace('X|dog','PP', regex=True)
```

Difference is better seen in this sample:

```
data = pd.Series(['A', 'BacX', 'dog', 'catdog', 'X'])

df = data.str.replace('X|^dog$','PP', regex=True)
print (df)
0         A
1     BacPP
2        PP
3    catdog <- dog is substring, so not replaced
4        PP
dtype: object

df = data.str.replace('X|dog','PP', regex=True)
print (df)
0        A
1    BacPP
2       PP
3    catPP <- dog is substring, so replaced
4       PP
dtype: object
```

EDIT: thank you @SeaBean for another case - If no substring for dog and there can be more than one word in each string, add word boundaries `\b\b`:

```
data.replace(r'X|\bdog\b','PP', regex=True)
```

Comment: `data.replace('X|dog', 'PP', regex=True)`

Comment: If no substring for `dog` and there can be more than one word in each string: `data.replace(r'X|\bdog\b','PP', regex=True)`

Comment: It's not working for more than two replacements....in this one I need to remove $, comma(,) and (-) everything to make it a perfect real number.                                     fifth = pd.Series(['12', '-$10', '$10,000'])   I did this:                          
fifth.str.replace(',|^-|^$','' , regex=True)     and I get this: 12 $10 $10000     which only remove negtive sign(-) and comma sign (,) from numbers. $ sign is as it is.

Comment: @KRUPALIRAO - tested and because `$` is special regex char (end of string) need escape it like `print(fifth.str.replace(',|^-\$|^\$','' , regex=True))`